Assessing whether the probability of being assigned treatment is equal (or reasonably close) between two individuals/groups
I'm currently studying the textbook Design of Observational Studies, second edition, by Rosenbaum. Chapter 3 Two Simple Models for Observational Studies says the following:

3.1 The Population Before Matching
In the population before matching, there are $L$ subjects, $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots, L$. Like the subjects in the randomized experiment in Chap. 2, each of these $L$ subjects has an observed covariate $x_\ell$, an unobserved covariate $u_\ell$, an indicator of treatment assignment, $Z_\ell$, where $Z_\ell = 1$ if the subject receives treatment or $Z_\ell = 0$ if the subject receives the control, a potential response to treatment, $r_{T\ell}$, which is seen if the subject receives treatment, $Z_\ell = 1$, a potential response to control, $r_{C\ell}$, which is seen if the subject receives the control, $Z_\ell = 0$, and an observed response, $R_\ell = Z_\ell r_{T\ell} + (1 - Z_\ell) r_{C\ell}$. Now, however, treatments are not assigned by the equitable flip of a fair coin.
In the population before matching, we imagine that subject $\ell$ received treatment with probability $\pi_\ell$, independently of other subjects, where $\pi_\ell$ may vary from one person to the next and is not known. More precisely,
$$\qquad \pi_\ell = Pr(Z_\ell = 1 \mid r_{T\ell}, r_{C\ell}, x_\ell, u_\ell). \qquad (3.1)$$

...

3.2 The Ideal Matching
Imagine that we could find two subjects, say $k$ and $\ell$, such that exactly one was treated, $Z_k + Z_\ell = 1$, but they had the same probability of treatment, $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$, and we made those two subjects into a matched pair. Obviously, it is something of a challenge to create this matched pair because we do not observe $u_k$ and $u_\ell$, and we observe either $r_{Tk}$ or $r_{Ck}$ but not both, and either $r_{T\ell}$ or $r_{C\ell}$ but not both. It is a challenge because we cannot create this pair by matching on observable quantities. We could create this pair by matching on the observable $x$, so $x_k = x_\ell$, and then flipping a fair coin to determine $(Z_k, Z_\ell)$, assigning one member of the pair to treatment, the other to control; that is, we could create this pair by conducting a randomized paired experiment, as in Chap. 2. Indeed, with the aid of random assignment, matching on $x$ may be prudent ([39]), but is not necessary to achieve $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$ because the $\pi$s are created by the experimenter. If randomization is infeasible or unethical, then how might one attempt to find a treated-control pair such that the paired units have the same probability of treatment, $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$?
Return for a moment to the study by Joshua Angrist and Victor Lavy [56] of class size and educational test performance, and in particular to the $L = 86$ pairs of Israeli schools in Sect. 1.3, one with between 41 and 50 students in the fifth grade ($Z = 1$) , the pairs being matched for a covariate $x$, namely the percentage of disadvantaged students. Strict adherence to Maimonides' rule would require the slightly larger fifth grade cohorts to be taught in two large classes and the slightly smaller fifth grade cohorts to be taught in one large class. As seen in Fig. 1.1, adherence to Maimonides' rule was imperfect by $\lvert r_T - r_C \rvert = 1$ or a little smaller in $L = 86$ (if the typical class size in their study, $\bar{r}(z)$, is average test scores in fifth grade). What separates a school with a slightly larger fifth grade cohort ($Z = 1$, 41-50 students) and a school with a slightly smaller fifth grade cohort ($Z = 0$, 31-40 students)? Well, what separates them is the enrollment of a handful of students in the 5th grade. It is reasonably plausible that whether or not a few more students enroll in the 5th grade is a relatively "haphazard" event, an event not strongly related to the average test performance ($r_T, r_C$) that the fifth grade would exhibit with a larger or smaller cohort. That is, building a $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ that are fairly close in the $L = 86$ matched pairs of two schools.
Properly understood, a “natural experiment” is an attempt to find in the world some rare circumstance such that a consequential treatment was handed to some people and denied to others for no particularly good reason at all, that is, haphazardly [4, 10, 38, 69, 91, 112, 124]. The word “natural” is a various connotations, but a “natural experiment” is a wild experiment, not a wholesome experiment, natural in the way that a tiger is natural, not in the way that oatmeal is natural. To express the same thought differently: to say that “it does seem reasonably plausible that $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ are fairly close” is to say that much less than "definitely, $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$ by the way treatments were randomly assigned." Haphazard is a far cry from randomized, a point given proper emphasis by Mark Rosenzweig and Ken Wolpin [112], by Timothy Besley and Anne Case [10] in reviews of several “natural experiments”, and by Guido Imbens and Donald Rubin in their discussions of “natural experiments”.
Nonetheless, it does seem reasonable to think that $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ are fairly close in the 86 paired Israeli schools in Fig. 1.1. This might be implausible in some other context, say in a national survey in the USA, where schools are funded by local government, so that class size might be predicted by the wealth or poverty of the local community. Even in the Israeli schools, there is a sense in which $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ were plausibly close depended upon: (1) matching in terms of percent of rather than class size.

...

Where do things stand? As has been seen, the ideal matching would pair individuals, $k$ and $\ell$, with different treatments, $z_k + z_\ell = 1$, but the same probability of treatment, $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$. If we could do this, we could reconstruct a randomized experiment from observational data; however, we cannot do this. The wise attempt to find “natural experiments” is the attempt to move towards this ideal. That is what you do with ideals: you attempt to move towards them. No doubt, many if not most “natural experiments” fail to produce this ideal pairing [10, 12]; moreover, even if one “natural experiment” once succeeded, there would be no way of knowing for sure that it had succeeded. A second attempt to approach the ideal is to find a context in which the covariates used to determine treatment assignment are measured covariates, $x_\ell$, not unobserved covariates, $u_\ell$, and then to match closely for the measured covariates. Although we cannot see $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ and so cannot see whether they are fairly close, perhaps there are things we can see that provide an incomplete and partial check on the closeness of $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$. This leads to the devices of quasi-experiments [13, 69, 119] mentioned in Sect. 1.2.4, such as multiple control groups [62, 84, 87], “multiple operationalism” or coherence [15, 47, 76, 90, 128], “control constructs” and known effects [68, 86, 87, 119, 133], and one or more pretreatment measures of what will become the response. When it “seems reasonably plausible that $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ are fairly close”, we will need to ask about the consequences of being close rather than equal, about the possibility they are somewhat less close than we had hoped, about the possibility that they are disappointingly far apart. Answers are provided by sensitivity analysis; see Sect. 3.4.

My question is with regards to whether it is reasonable to assume that $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$, or, at least, $\pi_k$ and $\pi_\ell$ are reasonably close, for an observational study (in order to determine causality). Take the case of a drug. Let's say that the drug company itself claims that the drug works for a certain demographic and will produce $results$ within $time$. Now assume that $k$ and $\ell$ are either describing two individuals of the same/said demographic or two groups (of individuals) of the same/said demographic. Now, let's say that we observe $k$ take the drug and observe that $\ell$ doesn't take the drug. Well, regardless of why $k$ took the drug and $\ell$ didn't, the drug company itself is making the claim that the drug should work on that demographic, so can we not just assume that $\pi_k = \pi_{\ell}$ in this case? In other words, since the onus / burden of proof is on the drug company, isn't it logically sound to assume that $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$ (or reasonably close) when looking to perform such an observational study (in order to determine causality), regardless of whether it is actually true? After all, if it turns out that it is false that $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$ (or reasonably close), then the experiment will fail to prove the hypothesis, which is entirely the fault of the drug company, right? And, after all, our entire goal/purpose with such experiments to determine causality is to assess whether some hypothesis is true, not to assess whether the correct hypothesis has been posed in the first place, right?

If someone claims, A causes B under all conditions and for everyone, yes, I suppose you might verify (falsify) that claim, but what's typically claimed is A causes B on average and under specific circumstances. For example, a clinical trial gives you an average for an effect for the people in that trial. Doesn't necessarily generalize to other groups or to the future.

Your quotation is far too long to be usable and even stretches the doctrine of fair use of copyrighted material.  Please simplify your post.

@whuber I've made some changes.

As an expert in this field, I cannot understand what you are trying to ask. Do you need to include a whole chapter to state your question? Can you please narrow down your question to something that can be answered?

@Noah $\pi_\ell$ is the probability that subject $\ell$ is allocated to treatment, right? And one of the main points that the author is making in the quoted text is that, if $\pi_\ell = \pi_k$, then we can infer causality from observational data, right? And the author then goes on to say that $\pi_\ell = \pi_k$ doesn't happen in reality. So [...]

[...] my point was that, in my fictional scenario, if both $k$ and $\ell$ fall under the demographic that the drug company itself claims will be helped by the treatment, if it so happens that we see $k$ take the drug/treatment and $\ell$ not take the drug treatment, what's wrong with considering this to be a valid natural experiment with $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$? After all, the drug company itself is claiming that this drug works for both $k$ and $\ell$, so why not take them at their word and conduct the experiment under that assumption? So, under this scenario, we [...]

[...] collect (observational) data from both $k$ and $\ell$ under the assumption that it is a valid natural experiment ($\pi_\ell = \pi_k$), and then perform causal inference based on that. Now, assume that the drug company's assumption/claim that the drug works for everyone in the demographic that $k$ and $\ell$ belong to is actually incorrect. Well, my understanding is that, in that case, this experiment will fail to show significance/causality, even though the drug actually might work / be shown to work in an experiment designed based on correct assumptions. But [...]

[...] this is the drug company's problem, not ours, right? Our job is not to predict, for the drug company, the conditions under which their drug will work – that's their job to specify; rather, our job is simply to verify the claims of the drug company, which we have successfully done. Therefore, it seems to me that assuming $\pi_\ell = \pi_k$ is perfectly valid in such a scenario – we simply accept / trust / take at face value the claims of the drug company.

@ThePointer I do not follow what's your interpretation of the condition $\pi_k = \pi_l$. How does the supposed assumption of the drug company that people with strata indexed by $k$ and $l$ can benefit from the drug mean that their probabilities of treatment are the same in an observational setting?

@Kuku The drug company sets the criteria for whom the drug is efficacious (that is, the demographic for whom the drug is efficacious). Now, say we want to search a city/area for such people to test the drug on. The drug company tells us that the drug should be efficacious for anyone who satisfies the aforementioned criteria, regardless of the area that they live in. Ok, we take them at their word. [...]

[...] We select a group of people, who satisfy the criteria, from one segment of the city, call them $k$; we then select another group of people, who satisfy the criteria, from another, different segment of the city, call them $\ell$. We give the drug to segment $k$ and observe them, and we also observe segment $\ell$ but do not give them the drug. [...]

[...] In telling us / claiming that the drug should be efficacious for anyone who satisfies the aforementioned criteria, regardless of the area that they live in, is the drug company not telling us / claiming that $\pi_k = \pi_\ell$ for these two groups, and so that such an observational experiment design is valid in inferring causality / efficaciousness of the drug? [...]

[...] And let's consider the scenario where the drug company is actually incorrect to claim that the drug should be efficacious for anyone who satisfies the aforementioned criteria, regardless of the area that they live in, and that the area that an individual lives in is actually an important criteria for determining the efficaciousness of the drug; then, in that case, the experiment will fail to show efficaciousness of the drug, right? [...]

[...] But that would be the fault of the drug company for claiming that the area that an individual lives in does not significantly affect the efficaciousness of the drug, right? As I said before, the job of the experimenters is to test the claims of the drug company (that is, take them at face value), not to come up with the correct claims for them. So, overall, was this not a perfectly valid experiment for inferring causality and testing whether the drug is efficacious?

@ThePointer In the example you mention, clearly $\pi_k \neq \pi_l$, since people in stratum $k$ receive the treatment with probability 1 and people in stratum $l$ receive the treatment with probability 0. Unless I am grossly misunderstanding your point...

@Kuku But isn't the entire point of the fact that we're dealing with observational data that we cannot control $\pi$, and so we want to look for two comparable experiments "in the wild" where $\pi = 1$ for one case (the treatment) and $\pi = 0$ for the other case (the control)? [...]

[...] But we only know that $\pi = 1$ for one case and $\pi = 0$ for the other a posteriori; before that (a priori), all we can do is try to determine whether the two cases/groups/whatever are "similar" – that is, whether $\pi_k \approx \pi_\ell$. By your logic, we would always have some $\pi = 1$ and some $\pi = 0$, since we observe a posteriori.
